Issue when adding a frame to a stacklayout in .NET MAUI
I am coding a kind of chat GUI, so when a entry event is excuted it shoud get the text inside it and set it into a label which then is set into a frame, so that that frame can be stablished in a stacklayout which is previously defined in the .xaml file. The problem is the text is gotten but the frame with the given text never appears on screen
i tried this
private void Entry_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e){
  
    string text = Entrada.Text;
   
    var rectangle = new Frame
    {
      
        Content = new Label
        {
            Text = text,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            FontAutoScalingEnabled = true,
            TextColor = Color.FromArgb("ffffff"),

         },
         MaximumHeightRequest = layout2.WidthRequest / 2,
         HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End,
         BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("#1D438A"),
    };

    Entry.Text = "";
    layout2.Children.Add(rectangulo);
}


Well the first thing I would tell you is don't use a frame, it's deprecated in MAUI, read for yourself https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/frame?view=net-maui-8.0

Use a Border and don't forget to define the Stroke and StrokeThickness. Note that your sample code won't compile, because it has spelling errors ("rectangle", "rectangulo").

From the official document Frame, we could know that

The Frame class existed in Xamarin.Forms and is present in .NET MAUI
for users who are migrating their apps from Xamarin.Forms to .NET
MAUI. If you're building a new .NET MAUI app it's recommended to use
Border instead, and to set shadows using the Shadow bindable property
on VisualElement.

So, you can use Border instead on Maui.
Please refer to the following code:
    private void OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = Entrada.Text;

        Border border = new Border
        {
            Stroke = Color.FromArgb("#C49B33"),
            Background = Color.FromArgb("#2B0B98"),
            StrokeThickness = 2,
            Padding = new Thickness(16, 8),
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            StrokeShape = new RoundRectangle
            {
                CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(10, 10, 10, 10)
            },
            Content = new Label
            {
                Text = ".NET MAUI",
                TextColor = Colors.White,
                FontSize = 18,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold
            }
        };


        layout2.Children.Add(border);
    }

For more information, please check document : Border.

Hi @diego alvarez, have you tried to use Border instead?
